# overlap between strcpy and memcpy

Tags: c

```
char pt[116];
```

pt is a message that contain 3 parts separated by ":" and the last part is random value

I have store each value in pointer

```
char* x = strtok( pt, ":" ) ;
char* y = strtok( NULL, ":" ) ;
char* z = strtok( NULL, ":" ) ;

printf("x:%s \n",x);
printf("y:%s \n",y);
printf("z:%s \n",z);
```

and later I need to some char to the first part

```
 memcpy(x,strcat(x,".pem"),strlen(x)+4) ); //==>this line cause the problem coz 
 x[strlen(x)]='\0';
 printf("%s\n",x);
 memcpy(y,y,strlen(y)+strlen(x)+4);
 printf("y is :%s\n",y); // here the output is wrong it prints the pem the  added part to x
```

So, what is the suggestion to add .pem to x without overlapping with the memcyp?

Comment: Could you explain what you meant to do in the line that caused the problem?

Comment: This code makes no sense.

Comment: What are you trying to do? `strcat(x, something)` will just return `x`. You then try to copy that `x` to `x`, but possibly using too many bytes. An additional problem is that we don't know if `strlen(x)` means the length before or after the call to `strcat`, because the order of evaluating parameters is not defined.

Comment: `x[strlen(x)]='\0';` serves no purpose.  `x[strlen(x)]` all ready has the value of `'\0'`.  The assignment does not change things.

Answer (score 1):

> **strtok**
>
> This function returns a pointer to the last token found in the string. A null pointer is returned if there are no tokens left to retrieve.

When you use `strcat` to ad `.pem` to the first part of the string (`x`) you are overwriting the `y` part.

You should isolate each string in a different array (c-string) and change the instead of the original one.

```
// Create a new container for x. Note: +1 is for the c-string null terminator
x_new[strlen(x)+4+1];

strcpy(x_new, x);
strcat(x_new, ".pem");
```